# Copy tags from mp3 to flac using kid3 and Dupeguru

Tags: command-line, mp3, tags, flac

I have a folder of mp3 files, and also one of flac files. I want the mp3 files to be replaced with the flac files, with the original tags of the mp3 files.

Using dupeguru, I can pinpoint which flac needs to overwrite which mp3. Also using dupeguru, I can use a command on the source file (mp3) and the dupe (flac). The command I would like to use is: copy tag data from mp3 to corresponding flac.
This command -theoretically- can be done with kid3. However, I cannot make it work.

I am trying only kid3 now, without dupeguru, to isolate the problem. No success.

I tried this:

c:\kid3\kid3-cli -c "copy 2 'c:\kid3\s.mp3'" -c "paste 2 'c:\kid3\s.flac'"

This does nothing. Well, for about half a second it looks the system is doing something, then I get the command prompt again. Nothing has been copied.

Then I tried this:

c:\kid3\kid3-cli -c "select 'c:\kid3\s.mp3'" -c "copy 2" -c "select 'c:\kid3\s.flac'" -c "paste 2" -c "save"

This gives me:

> c:\kid3\s.mp3 has not been found.

But I am sure it is there. :)

What am I doig wrong?

Comment: Did you run these command as administrator ?

Comment: I did not, but I just did and the results are the same.